# Photoshop how to make one thing and link it to other psd

Tags: photoshop, psd

I am wondering if it is possible to make a stuffs in one psd and link it to another psd so that when I change one the other changes also. I know it sounds kind of weird but I am going to need this.

I am designing a website with about 20 templates and every time I change something in the header I need to open all the other psd and apply the changes. And I cannot do all the templates in only one psd for business reasons.

Google did not help me much or maybe am searching with wrong keywords.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Sure, go to the `File` menu and click `Place linked...` to link a Smart Object.

Comment: Actually my PS6 is in french and I just simply dont have this in my menu. Thats why I've spent all this time trying to figure out how to do it. I simply cant !!!

Comment: PS6? That is years too old :-( Embedding linked Smart Object was only introduced very recently.

Comment: ok thanks. It did took me some time to understand this. I would have thought that this feature would exist like in PS5 as its not really that big deal

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to the latest Photoshop, which has this feature, I would suggest to overthink your workflow.
Actually I would suggest it anyways, because I think, designing websites using multiple PSDs, possible having 70% or more showing the same, isn't that efficient. So far, I personally was never in need of doing that.

So, if your websites aren't changing drasticly on every page, I don't see any need in multiple PSDs. This way, the urge for your requested feature (that you can't have anyway without a new Photoshop) would probably be lessend.

Comment: Hi, I am not sure to understand what you mean to overthink the workflow. My pages do change drastically well for the content. But the header, nav and footer the remain the same. I tried having everything in one psd but every time i shift to another template i need to move the footer and the nav bar as the templates are different.

Comment: Well it's not important if you have to move the footer (don't know why to move the navigation). Just expand the canvas as needed and eventually you have all sitting in one PSD. After export all previews, just crop the ones that need it.
Anyway, everyone to his likeing ... :)